# WebRTC Stream Freezes When Picture Complexity Increases

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, h.264, x264

I am developing an application that uses WebRTC to display a live video stream being captured from a V4L2 source.  The stream originates from a Linux box that has a DVI-USB capture card, is encoded to H264 by ffmpeg and sent to RTP, received by a Janus WebRTC server which is accessed by the web interface.

Here is my current ffmpeg command - pretty simple:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -vf "transpose=1,scale=768:1024" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtp rtp://10.116.80.86:8004

I can't go into details, but the DVI source generates a portrait 768x1024 image that initially is a simple image where the only movement is a small clock near the center that increments every second.  At this stage, everything appears to work great.  The image is high-quality and continuous/smooth in the browser.

Once I interact with the DVI source, a more complex image is generated, with some text/lines in the upper half.  Still not very complex - only 2 colors involved and some basic 1px line shapes, and only the little clock is moving.  At this point, the video starts to freeze frequently, and only updates once in a while for a few seconds.  Bandwidth should not be an issue here, and the bitrate appears to stay high.  However, many fewer frames are decoded.

I have also tried scaling the video down to 480x640 from 768x1024 and with that change the issue does not occur.  However,  I really need the full resolution and, again, there should not be a bandwidth issue here.

I have also tried capturing the output of ffmpeg to a file rather than streaming to RTP and in the file everything is good.

Here is a screenshot of the WebRTC internals (in Edge) for this stream.  You can clearly see when the video image changes from the simple clock to including more shapes & text (nothing is changed here other than the image from the DVI source):

[image: WebRTC internals plots]

In Firefox, the video just freezes whenever frames are not decoded.  In Edge, the video goes black after a moment with no frames decoded.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for future Googlers:

I ended up figuring out that this was due to the WebRTC server (Janus) running on a Raspberry Pi.  Apparently the Pi 3B+ was powerful enough to handle the packet flow when the bitrate was low (just the clock), but when the rate got higher it would choke.

I re-hosted Janus on a more powerful server and all is working well.